# Sum with Datedif Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ihave a formula like this

> =IF(DATEDIF(D4;DATE(2014;8;31);"Y")>15;DATEDIF(D4;DATE(2014;8;31);"Y")*12500+VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(C4;1));$U$22:$Z$25;7;FALSE);0)

But returned a #REF! results, can you tell me what's wrong on this formula?

Comment: What value is C4 in the above post?

Comment: A string, like this : 1AS-SKA-1A

Comment: I would work with a small sample, maybe two records exhibiting the issue and then break apart your formula. You may find the culprit that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious mistake I see is here :

`VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(C4;1));$U$22:$Z$25;7;FALSE`

`$U$22:$Z$25` has only 6 columns but you want to get value from the 7th.